# Accepting self-signed certtificates with Java when connecting through SSLSocketFactory

Tags: java

There were some answers on how to accept self-signed SSL-connections with Java here. But none of that worked when connecting to a server through SSLSocketFactory. Can anyone give me example-code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like this below. This Java code will enable you to accept all certificates

```
        public static class NukeSSLCerts {
protected static final String TAG = "NukeSSLCerts";

public static void nuke() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];  
                    return myTrustedAnchors;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
            }
        };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) { 
    }
}
```

}

And execute like this

```
    new NukeSSLCerts().nuke();
```

Comment: I'm not working with Android. And I have to accept any connection for which I don't have the certificate.

Comment: That's what I want.

Comment: Hope it answered your question?

Comment: I'm not working with (Https)UrlConnection. I'm giving a class a SocketFactory-object, in my case a SslSocketFactory-object, and what this class internally does is not up to me.